# In c++, in a for loop, how do you print out a string once with

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, int

What I'm dealing with is a nested for loop that finds perfect numbers. The iterations to find the perfect number came about pretty quickly. However, I need the output to show a string that says, "perfect number found" and have that happen once. Then on the same line, print out all the perfect numbers. So for example, lets say I have two inputs, 1 to 30.

That means that the perfect numbers are 6 and 28.
The output should be something like.

Perfect numbers: 6 28.

What I'm confused on is how to print out just that string once in the for loop I have created. Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                sum += j;
            }
        }
        if (i * 2 == sum)
        {
            std::cout << i << " ";
            count++;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "number of perfect numbers found: " << count << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print it before the loop ?

Comment: It makes sense to do so but I want it to print out once perfect numbers are found.

Comment: You can have a bool that says if you printed the string yet(which will default to false), and the first thing in loop you can check if the bool is still false, if it is print the string and set it to true.

Comment: Put the perfect numbers found in a vector. After the end of the loop, check its size and if it's greater then zero, print the message and the numbers.

Comment: You can use an `if()` statement after the loop, and only produce output if perfect numbers have been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do it "in the for loop"? Do it before you enter the for loop.

Or, if you want to make sure you found at least one perfect number before committing yourself to printing that string, then on the line where you print out the individual values, instead of:

```
std::cout << i << " ";
```

just say:

```
std::cout << (count == 0 ? "Perfect numbers: " : "") << i << " ";
```

Comment: That does not make sense to me.  OP wants to print a list of numbers at the end. How would you know what they were at the beginning?

Comment: So would ternary conditions be the default go to to create string values for these types of situations?

Comment: @harmic This is not that hard. On each iteration through the outer loop, he's printing out one of his results (if there is one). He just needs to know whether it's the first one. If it's the first one, then print the initial string before the value.

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. I don't know if it's "the go to" way, but it certainly answers the question: how to get the string to print just once. I tend to like it because it's concise, but that's just a stylistic preference. I'm sure we can come up with many other ways.

Comment: @harmic Ah, I see, you misinterpreted my answer. I did not mean to print that at the beginning, but in the same place where he had his original print statement. I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this and just add the print with the cout

```
for(i=start; i<=end; i++)
    {
        sum = 0;

        /* Check whether the current number i is Perfect number or not */
        for(j=1; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(i % j == 0)
            {
                sum += j;
            }
        }

        /* If the current number i is Perfect number */
        if(sum == i)
        {
            cout <<i<<" ,";
        }
    }
```